Use callback_data in chained function in telebot
In the send_service_names function, I get information from the api, I start looping, and using InlineKeyboardMarkup, I set the information obtained from the api into callback_data, and using the arg in the next function, i.e. send_service_information, I use the obtained information and According to that information, I will send the next request to the server, and finally, with the obtained answer, I will create a menu like the previous function. But the main question here is that I want to send this using callaback_data to the next function (in a chain), but When I run the code and the user clicks on the menu, the next function code is not executed and the same function, send_service_information, is executed again.
from telebot import types
from json import loads
from math import floor

from services.apiPhone import getServices, getInfo
from services.apiPayment import createPayment

TOKEN = ""

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_message(message):
  bot.reply_to(message,"درود به ربات ما خوش اومدی️")

  markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,one_time_keyboard=True)
  virtualPhone = types.KeyboardButton("شماره مجازی")

  markup.add(virtualPhone)

  msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'لطفا یکی از گزینه های زیر را انتخاب کنید:',reply_markup=markup)
  bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,process_name_step)

def process_name_step(message):
  if message.text == "شماره مجازی":
    send_service_names(message)
  else:
    pass

def send_service_names(message):
  serviceInfo = loads(getServices())
  keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

  for i in range(len(serviceInfo)):
    buttonMarkup = types.InlineKeyboardButton(serviceInfo[i]["name"],callback_data= serviceInfo[i]["id"] + "," + serviceInfo[i]["name"])
    keyboard.add(buttonMarkup)

  msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"لطفا سرویس مورد نظر خود را انتخاب کنید:",reply_markup=keyboard)

  bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,send_service_information)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def send_service_information(call):

  serviceInfo = call.data
  idService = serviceInfo.split(",")[0]
  nameService = serviceInfo.split(",")[1]

  try:
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, nameService)

    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    service = loads(getInfo(idService))
    
    if "RESULT" in service and int(service["RESULT"] == 0):
      bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"شماره ای برای این سرویس موجود نیست")
      exit

    for i in range(len(service)):
        if int(service[i]["count"]) > 0:
          buttonMarkup = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
              f"نام کشور: {service[i]['cname']} / قیمت: {floor(int(service[i]['amount']) * 0.2 + int(service[i]['amount'])):,} تومان"
              , callback_data=service[i]["id"])
          keyboard.add(buttonMarkup)

    print(call.message.text)
    msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f"{nameService} تعرفه سرویس", reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,handle_button_click)

  except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

def handle_button_click(message):
  print("hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  bot.polling()

